# Not able to apply jquery to appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dynamic, jquery-append

I am adding `#show_data` button dynamically, but not able to use jQuery on that button. `Hi! data` is never logged
How do I add Scripts to dynamic elements?

```
<body>

    <button id="show_fields">Show Fields</button>
    <div id="button"></div>

    <script>

        $("#show_fields").click(function(){
            console.log('Hi! fields');
            $("#button").html("<button id=\"show_data\">Show data</button>");
        });

        $("#show_data").click(function(){
            console.log('Hi! data');
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for attaching events to dynamically added element:

```
$("#button").on('click','#show_data',function(){
   console.log('Hi! data');
});
```

Comment: but i am using .html() which would replace the existing elements in `#button`

Comment: Shouldn't be problem for you then.